# ListView android shows nothing

Tags: java, android, android-listview

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

The speech recognizer returns some words he has recognized, and I want to show them in a textField, now I read that it must be done with a list so I wrote this:

In the oncreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

where mList is a private ListView var.

This is the result function then:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches);
mList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

In my activity_main.xml I have added this:

```
  ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Somehow the program isn't showing my list.

I followed this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in logcat?

Comment: No, I don't have any exceptions.

Comment: "the program isn't showing my list", you are not seeing the content inside the list (or) dropdown itself not showing up?

Comment: Doesn't show anything. The layout didn't changed after my voice. And I just tested my matches array is not empty there are 12 results or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:layout_height="0dip" seems wrong.  It should probably be "wrap_content" instead.

Comment: I changed that to wrap_content but still doesn't work... Thanks for the help already.

Answer (score 0):

I had some double list in my xml with the same name.. :-) Works fine after change 0dip to wrap content. Thanks everybody!